# Grails custom marshaller exception handling

Tags: grails

I'm writing a custom marshaller for RESTful app written in Grails 2.3.7, which contians service method calls:

```
class CommentMarshaller implements MarshallerRegistrar {

    @Autowired
    RatingService ratingService

    @Override
    void register() {
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Comment) { Comment comment ->
            def total = ratingService.getSumRating(comment)
            if (!total) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("to be caught")
            }
            return [
                id: comment.id,
                created: comment.created,
                text: comment.text,
                authorName: comment.author.username,
                authorId: comment.author.id,
                rating: total
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to catch exceptions, that were thrown from marshaller in my ErrorController:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "500"(controller: "error", action: "handleError")
    }
}
```

It works perfectly when some error occurs in controller code, but when exception is thrown from marshaller, Grails tries to find error.gsp and render stacktrace there.
How can I redirect errors from marshaller to ErrorController?